# В node.js express не передаются POST-параметры

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, express

В node.js express не передаются POST-параметры из фронта, т.е. если смотреть поступивший запрос, то поле request.body == {}

Конфигурация express:

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require("cors");

var newTask = require('./routes/new_task');
var app = express();

app.use(express.json() );
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: true
})); 

app.use('/new-task', newTask);

app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:*',
    credentials: true}));
```

Запрос отправляю так:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

fetch(PLACE_TASK_ENDPOINT, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: myHeaders,
            mode: 'no-cors',
            cache: 'no-cache',
            body: JSON.stringify({a: 1})
        });
```

Если сделать запрос через curl в командной строке, то параметры в express видно.

Comment: Вангую, что вы пытаетесь увидеть данные у OPTIONS запроса

Comment: @Alexey Ten, так вроде в заголовке указываю запрос POST и на бэкенде у роутера принимаю в методе post. Можете пояснить что имеете ввиду?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request

Comment: @AlexeyTen, похоже, что нет, на сервере тип запроса явно светится как POST.

Comment: Если при отправке запроса изменить Content-Type на 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' данные в body видно.

Comment: Я на 99% уверен что дело в OPTIONS. Как вы на сервере проверяли тип запроса?

Comment: router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.method);
}); выводит POST

Comment: Ну, что бы ещё мог вывести `router.post`. Но вы то используете `app.use` который ловит все запросы

Comment: Ну так я в router.post и смотрю body у запроса POST, т.е. это точно не OPTIONS